# Node version not updated on execution after using nvm

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, session, cookies

I'm running a node server that sends and receives a cookie to and from a browser. I'm using firebase admin to create the session cookie and verify it.

```
router.post("/api/login", async function loginResponse(request, response) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "HTTP://aurl.com");
    const idToken = request.body.idToken.toString();

    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
    admin
        .auth()
        .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
        .then(
            async (sessionCookie) => {
                const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true };
                response.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
                console.log(sessionCookie);
                result = h.setResult(
                    { idToken },
                    true,
                    "login cookie set",
                    h.errorEnum.NONE
                );
                return await c.simpleResponse(result, response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error.code, request.data);
                error.code == "auth/invalid-id-token"
                    ? response
                          .status(401)
                          .send({ msg: "UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!" })
                    : console.log(error);
            }
        );
});
```

On the frontend, I've set credentials to be "included" in the request headers to ensure that the cookie is being sent (although, I'm not 100% sure if this will do the trick).

```
document
    .getElementById("login")
    .addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const login = event.target.login.value;
        const password = event.target.password.value;
        console.log(login, password);
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(login, password)
            .then(({ user }) => {
                return user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
                    console.log(idToken);
                    return fetch(
                        "http://aurl.com:3001/api/login",
                        {
                            method: "POST",
                            headers: {
                                Accept: "application/json",
                                "Content-Type":
                                    "application/json",
                            },
                            credentials: "include",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                idToken,
                            }),
                        }
                    );
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                return firebase.auth().signOut();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
        return false;
```

However, my issue seems unrelated to all of this. It seems that one of the packages has an issue for some reason.

Every time the request is sent from the frontend, the backend raises an error

```
ReferenceError: BigInt is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/backend/node_modules/jose/lib/help/rsa_primes.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/backend/node_modules/jose/lib/help/key_utils.js:9:23)
```

I can't seem to pinpoint why this issue arises. I've thought maybe the issue arose from a node_module called "jose" so I updated my node version to 14.17.1. According to the "jose" package it is compatible with this version so I'm not sure what's wrong.
source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose

Here is a list of modules I'm using if it helps:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

Comment: I'm curios what is `result = h.setResult()` ? Also where are the variables `h` and `c` declared? Please share the complete code.

Comment: Ah, so those are constants that I've defined in other files. What I've done is I've modularized the responses and made the result structures consistent for all responses. I've separated them into different files. Either way, it's unrelated to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure why this helped, but instead of using `nvm` to update node, I used `n`, the node version manager. That seemed to do the trick for me.

If someone knows why this may be the case, it might be good to know.